# Azure Communication Services - Delete 3rd Party Chat Messages

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I am trying to implement a chat functionality using azure communication services. One special use case is, that this chat must be administrated by one single administrative role.

This administrative role called "moderated" shall be allowed to delete selected messages from other chat participants.

Couldn't find a way to do this so far, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported.

> Participants don't have write access to messages sent by other participants, which means only the message sender can update or delete their sent messages.

Please refer to the [User Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/chat/concepts#user-access) section of the documentation for more details.

You can upvote the [Implement basic Roles for the Chat Clients](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/2f588183-a5b3-ec11-a81c-0022484ee92d) idea if you'd like to see this implemented in the future.